# How to mock variable in unit test android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

Searched on google about, how to mock a variable in unit testing and seen some suggestions, for my case its not working. my scenario is,

```
class Keys {

private static Keys sKeys;
private String enKey = null;

static synchronized sKeys getInstance() {
    if(sKeys == null) {
        sKeys = new Keys();
    }
    return sKeys;
}

Boolean isLocked() {
    if(enKey == null ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the class, i have written. Unit test of the class is below,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)     
public class KeysTest {

@Test
public void isLocked_Test() {
    Keys key = Keys.getInstance();
    Key.isLocked();
   // Here in isLocked function I want to mock the enKey value to other than null
   }
}
```

Here, i want to call isLocked function, and i want to set or mock the **enKey** variable value to other than null.

How i can do that?
Could anyone help me on that?

Comment: Maybe add the code you want to test. That will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @arne.z Edited my question. please see it.

Answer (score 0):

please add accessor methods for your fields otherwise your code will not be compatible with Test Driven Development. if you have a method like 'getEnkeys()' that will return 'enKey' then you can easily mock the method 'getEnKeys' to return a different value using any mocking frameworks. for example using *mockito*  : `Mockito.when(key.getEnkeys()).thenReturn("someValue");`

If you really want to go woth current implementation then try with `@InjectMocks` annotation with the instance variable in conjunction with some initializer method like

```
@Before public void initMocks() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
```